# How easy is it really for malicious websites to steal session cookies or other data?

Tags: cookies, chrome, websites

I would like to know how feasible an attack on a web browser is. Is that something that occurs frequently or is it difficult to manage for a malicious website to steal sensitive data using remote code exploits?

**Also is it secure enough to have several Chrome profiles to prevent theft of sensitive data if a malicious website is visited?**

Comment: Are you asking how common exploitation of zero-day attacks in the wild is? Or are you assuming an unpatched browser? Or are you asking about website vulns, rather than browser vulns? There's no way, in theory, for a malicious site to learn anything meaningful about other sites from the browser; that's what same-origin policy is for. If you're assuming the browser is compromised, the question is how and why; Chrome has a robust security program and gets patched very regularly, but if you don't install the updates, you give attackers a chance to weaponize newly-patched vulns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't in theory be possible for a website to access cookies/sessions other than for it's own domain, however there are browser exploits that can do this. Now days it is becoming increasingly difficult for these attacks to work.

Prior to about 2014 you would see a lot of web browser exploits that would allow malicious websites to download and execute malware or access private data. There were a number of reasons for this. Partly there were a lot of web browser plugins that were used that tended to not be updated much such as flash, activex, Java and a lot of attacks would use these. The other thing is that the way web browsers are designed has changed, so now days modern browsers use sandboxing to prevent processes accessing protected memory. You can search for web browser exploit kits if you want to learn more about the above.

In response to your question: No I don't believe having multiple Chrome profiles would defend against these kind of exploits. If an exploit can allow a website to bypass the sandbox and access protected memory then a sperate profile probably won't do much. The best thing to to is to keep your browser up to date, don't install untrusted plugins, use an ad blocker and don't click on or visit suspicious wbesites if you can avoid it.